# Notebook smooth scrolling

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to enable smooth scrolling in vscode notebooks?
I'd like to use the up/down arrows to scroll through the notebook and not have it shift focus from cell to cell.

In Jupyter notebooks (webserver), it can be done by inserting the following code in the first cell:

```
%%javascript 
 
Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.remove_shortcut('up');
Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.remove_shortcut('down');
```

Unfortunately, the same command does not work in vscode.

How do I enable it?